# mySQL Not Working as expected

Tags: mysql, select

Basic example is this:

3 tables:

Orders, holds only the OID I need to link with Cart;

Products, holds the product Name, and SKU I need;

Cart, holds the OID and product Name.

It is an old system, but I am trying to create a report where the User enters the SKU to get all orders that relate to it:

```
SELECT * FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN cart c ON (o.id = c.session_id) 
WHERE product_name = 
     (SELECT product_sku FROM products WHERE product_code = c.prorduct_name)
ORDER by sdate DESC;
```

This does not work, I have tried to add the join cart in with sub select, but that did not work either.  They give me either no results, or an error with the column being found.

Have I given enough information for this to make sense ?  And any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

## UPDATED

```
 SELECT * FROM orders o 
   LEFT JOIN cart c ON (o.id = c.session_id) 
   LEFT JOIN products p ON (p.product_code = c.product_name) 
 WHERE {$sku} o.senddate BETWEEN '{$_REQUEST["date3"]}' AND
  '{$_REQUEST["date4"]}' ORDER BY o.senddate ASC
```

I managed to achieve the result using workbench and basically putting the code in a different order.  This seemed to do the trick :)

Comment: see pproducts it's typo error or you used it like that

Comment: Thanks, it was a typeO :)

Comment: Are you sure you want to compare the `cart.product_name` to `products.product_sku` ...? Comparing name with name might make a little more sense perhaps? Plus, you said the user enters the SKU as the sole search criterion - so why does that not show up in any of the WHERE clauses?

Comment: The column names referenced in the SELECT statement don't seem to correspond to the columns that each table "holds". What we don't see is the actual table definitions, including primary keys and foreign keys, or even any sample data we could make inferences from.  There is insufficient information to debug the problem. it's not possible to recommend a SELECT statement; the only answers to this question (as currently presented) are going to be "guesses".

Comment: Does the error for the column not being found involves `prorduct_name` of table `cart`?

Comment: @spencer7593 you are right about the "guesses" part.

Comment: Provide some sample data as a http://sqlfiddle.com/ please.

Comment: I see I have been marked down...   The query is actually correct in way of wording, as I said its a very old system.  product.code is also, in that table, the title.  Not sure why either.  Last night, however, I did manage to get it right.  Edited OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a small typo in your query
you write `c.prorduct_name` should it be `c.product_name`. Use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`

Additionally if i understand the schema of your tables correctly you can re-write your query like this.

```
SELECT * FROM orders AS o,
cart AS c,
products AS p
WHERE c.product_name = p.product_code
AND o.id = c.session_id
AND product_sku = 'the_selected_SKU'
ORDER by sdate DESC;
```

Comment: Your code is different to mine slightly, but it did work also, so marked as Answer.  Thank you :)